# Imbalanced data identification with Shannon entropy

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, class-imbalance

I was studying about the imbalanced data. Then I had a question , how would someone know that which data is imbalanced or not by looking at its percentage(20,30 or 40).

Then I read an answer on stack exchange it says:
**You could use the Shannon entropy as a measure of balance.
On a data set of n instances, if you have k classes of size ci you can compute entropy as follows:
H=−∑i=1kcinlogcin.
This is equal to:
0 when there is one single class. In other words, it tends to 0 when your data set is very unbalanced
logk when all your classes are balanced of the same size nk
Therefore, you could use the following measure of Balance for a data set:
Balance=Hlogk=−∑ki=1cinlogcin.logk
which is equal to:
0 for a unbalanced data set
1 for a balanced data set**

I understand this part and tried as well but I got a value of "Balance" in decimal(0.79, 0.92 etc)

By looking at this decimal values how would i know that the data is balanced or imbalanced?